# Backward feature elimination removes significant one-sided associations?

Tags: regression, correlation, statistical-significance, p-value, inference

I’m fitting data to a linear regression model. In the end, I want a model that only includes significant IVs with p values <= 0.05, so I’m looping through and at each iteration removing the IV with the highest p value, re-fitting, until all IVs are <= 0.05.

Wouldn’t this method potentially eliminate variables that might have, for example, a significant positive linear association with the DV (e.g., p value of 0.1, but if we divide by 2, it would be 0.05)?

Wouldn’t it make more sense to do the feature elimination based on half of the p value? The purpose of the model is for understanding associations and statistical inference.

I know there’s a lot of “it depends” here, but just looking for general advice.

Answer (score 1):

While I do not follow the rationale of dividing the p-value by two, you are correct that such a backward elimination procedure might leave out important predictors, and this is one of the reasons why stepwise regression is so problematic in many cases.

Perhaps much worse for your analysis, however, is that all of the parameter inferences are distorted as soon as you start doing stepwise regression. The coefficient test statistics are calculated based on the assumption that those features were selected from the beginning. However, stepwise selection of variables means that the distributions of your coefficients has now conditioned on performing the stepwise procedure, which is not accounted for in the usual test statistics, p-values, or confidence intervals. This relates to criticisms 2, 3, 4, and 7 discussed [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/) by Frank Harrell.

Your goal of having a model that only includes statistically significant predictors starts out sounding reasonable, perhaps noble, but can lead to a great many problems.